# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with Socket.IO on Java Server

Tags: java, javascript, sockets, socket.io

I've got the following problem: I'm running a JAVA Server with socket.io (netty socket.io - https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) - I'm trying to access this server from a different web-server through javascript.

For a test I'm trying to get the Demo Chat running (https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio-demo).

The Problem now is that i keep getting the following

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myserver/socket.io/1/?t=1400445162388. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'myclient.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So the big question is: How do i allow access to my java server? I've found a few solutions saying to add the 'header' to it, but i have no idea where to put that. Does that go into the socket.io server code?

I think i need something like this, placed somewhere on the JAVA server:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

This is the code which starts the server:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setHostname("localhost");
    config.setPort(80);
    final SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
    //ChatObject wurde extra implementiert, ggf. loeschen
    server.addJsonObjectListener(ChatObject.class, new DataListener<ChatObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onData(SocketIOClient client, ChatObject data, AckRequest ackRequest) throws Exception {
            // broadcast messages to all clients
            server.getBroadcastOperations().sendJsonObject(data);
        }
    });
    server.start();
```

and this is the output im getting from the server:

```
error: The specified resource was not found: /static/flashsocket/WebSocketMain.swf
error: The specified resource was not found: /static/flashsocket/WebSocketMainInsecure.swf
info: Session store / pubsub factory used: {}MemoryStoreFactory (local session store only)
info: SocketIO server started at port: {}80
```

Any help is greatly appreciated ! Thank you

Comment: No; you need to configure Socket.io to allow your origin.

Comment: thanks @SLaks can you give me a direction on how and where to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

Comment: thanks, i already found that page. if i'm getting it right it says that by default origin "*" is set, allowing access from everywhere, right? also, this is a java server so i can't use java script code, right ? or do i have to add this on my client side java ?

Comment: i mean client side java script

Comment: any idea on where to start ? @SLaks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've confronted the similar problem yesterday and solved it mostly. I'd like to share my solution here.
Firstly, we all know it is so called CORS standard (cross-origin resource sharing) which means one resource we opened up from website A request another resource from website B ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)). Therefore, in your case, assume the original web server (with domain AAA.com) and your netty server (domain BBB.com), then append this line to your netty server to get permission：

```
config.setOrigin("http://AAA.com");
```

Note that you cannot use wildcard (*) for *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* in netty-socketio as it set credentials (i.e., *Access-Control-Allow-Credentials*)  TRUE by default ([see here](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio/commit/66e7408bbd0ff96103dcfc2b4516c05b2f2abc3d)). Keep in mind that **the browser will also reject any response that does not have the *Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true* header, and not make the response available to the invoking web content**. Hope these help.

The followings are my library versions:
**netty-socketio version**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.corundumstudio.socketio</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-socketio</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**socket.io.javascript**

```
script(type="text/javascript", src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) 1.7.1 or 1.6.6 version. Ability to set custom Access-Control-Allow-Origin via Configuration.origin parameter was added in this version.

Comment: I am having the same problem and tried the above solution but it didn't help. I have created the issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78232355/cross-origin-request-blocked-from-socket-io-js-in-springboot-application